# Pasting a large chunk of code to tmux on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

Suppose I open a python on tmux.
If I paste a large chunk of code which involves some delays and print statements, tmux will return some random rubbish to me.

For example, if I copy the following code (please manually to repeat the middle part)

```
import time
print("hello world");time.sleep(0.02)
print("hello world");time.sleep(0.02)
.
.  (please repeat it at least 50 times)
.
print("hello world");time.sleep(0.02)
```

and paste it to the tmux window. It doesn't return what we expected but some random mix of the original input.

```
>>> print("hello world");time.sleep(0.02print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0.02print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0.02print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0.02print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0.02print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0.02print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0.02print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202print("hello world");time.sleep(0.0202
```

PS:

1. It doesn't happen on my linux machine, but only my Mac
2. It also doesn't happen when I open python without tmux.

So my question: is there anything I am missing? or is it a bug of tmux?

tmux 1.9a, python 2.x and 3.x, mac osx yosemite.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? I can actually reproduce  this without `tmux` in iTerm2. I don't know what the problem is, but it certainly seems independent of `tmux`.

Comment: I am using Terminal. I seems that iTerm is using something similar to `tmux` and it has the same bug.

Comment: Interesting. `iTerm` doesn't actually *use* `tmux`; it can communicate with an instance to map things like `tmux` windows to `iTerm` panes, so I'm not sure how an input problem would be shared (but I don't really know how the integration is implemented).